# Where's Mvemba's Church Property?

Tags: civilization-6

Civilization 6.

Mvemba a Nzinga is supposed to gain all Benefits of any Religion that has established itself in the majority of his cities.

Well, I'm playing with him, nearly all my cities have the same Religion, and one of its benefits is Church Property, which gives 2 Gold per turn per city of any civ following that Religion. **By my account, I was supposed to get that Gold. But I'm not getting it.** I don't see that Gold in my Income report, where I had seen it when playing with other Leaders who actually founded a Religion with that Benefit.

**Are there any explanations?** Is this a known bug? Is it fixed in the expansions, which I don't have? What *other* Benefits Mvemba doesn't get?

Comment: All I can recommend is to double check you're not receiving it, and that it's a belief of the religion you're following in the majority of your cities. His perk is that he receives all the beliefs of any religion that has established itself as Kongo's majority religion, not just the Follower beliefs. So anyone else wouldn't get follower beliefs (and Church Property is a Follower belief, which means this is possibly bugging out)